# ES query_string different boost for values

Tags: elasticsearch

In normal ES query I do for example:
(in query.bool.should ... )

```
{
   "term": {
     "processedText": {
     "boost": 1.9599999999999997,
     "value": "some_value"
   }
 }
 },
{
 "term": {
    "processedText": {
    "boost": 3.4489795918367347,
     "value": "other_value"
```

As you see different boost values from different values which I query for.
How can I do the same using query_string ?

```
 "query_string": {
            "query": "(something AND test) OR (foo OR bar OR nothing) NOT (abc OR xyz)",
            "default_field": "text"
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See ["Boosting" paragraph at the Query-String-Query doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boosting):

> Use the boost operator ^ to make one term more relevant than another.
>   ...
>   Boosts can also be applied to phrases or to groups.

Example:

```
"query_string": {
    "query": "(something AND test)^5 OR (foo^2 OR bar^1.5 OR nothing) NOT (abc OR xyz)",
    "default_field": "text"
}
```